# Antivirus behaving in a strange way

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I was writing my program as usual, but when I compiled one file the Windows Defender treated it as "Trojan:Script/Wacatac.B!ml" couple times before suddenly becoming silent, then I did a full scan and it revealed "PUA:Win64/CoinMiner" I deleted it and continued working. Some time after, I started working on another file, compiled it and antivirus showed "Win32/DefenseEvasion.HP!ml". I haven't encountered anything like this before.

What should I do about it?

P.S. The program consists of client (1st file) and server (2nd file). Client is simple paint-like program (although, very limited), which sends image data to the server, server saves it in the directory, where .exe file is located, after that, client saves image in the Downloads folder.

Comment: If these files are being generated by you, submit them to Microsoft as a false positive, then until that report is processed create an exception for the folder that contains the files.

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Comment: Bitdefender just identified all my personal dev projects as a particular trojan, because I commonly create a test ui that I call "stub". seems like it really doesn't like files named stub.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add directories and files to [exclusion in Windows Defender](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26):

1. Go to Start  > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection.
2. Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings, and then under Exclusions, select Add or remove exclusions.alternate text
3. Select Add an exclusion, and then select from files, folders, file types, or process. A folder exclusion will apply to all subfolders within the folder as well.

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail on how OP will do this?

Answer (score -2):

May be the Antivirus is right.
Check your Task Manager whether your application is consuming high CPU or something like that.
Crypto mining apps may exist without you being aware of it.

Comment: I've deleted it